# XMLHttpRequest access denied

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, request

I got problem with request in ajax. I wrote site script like that:

```
var url = "http://url/api/render";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http.overrideMimeType) {
            http.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {//ie
        try {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
http.open('POST', url, false);
```

After call the function, I got "Access denied" error. What I do wrong ? For testing I typed google address ... this same error

Comment: Perhaps you're running into the Same Origin Policy?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Consider using an XHR wrapper - it makes life simpler; it *doesn't* need to be jQuery.

Comment: @user2246674 - doesn't help

Comment: @David 
Address looks like: example.com/api_file/api_action

Comment: @adrian the point is do you try to access example.com from example.net? That is the point of the same orfin policy.

Comment: @rekire 
I got loaded page in desktop program. After clicking on anchor, javascript will call this function to the server

Comment: In this case David has absolutly right. There is no way to achive that with a local storred file. You have to do that compleatly online.